# how to do inverse of multi-level wavelet decomposition

Tags: matlab, multi-level, wavelet

i applied 4-level wavelet decomposition to an image

now i need to do inverse of this wavelet transform from the 4-levels of A, H, V, D.... i saw the function waverec2... but to use that function i need [c, s]... how can i reconstruct [c,s] from the 4-levels of A, H, V, D

Answer (score 0):

Below is an example of image denoising using wavelets. It might be of use
http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/43996-image-denoising